# ServiceStack NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I am new to servicestack and am really enjoying it, however I can not for the life of me figure of why this is occuring.

```
I have mapped it as ROUTES.Add<images>("/Images"); in the APPHOST.cs
```

I use Rest Console(chrome plugin) to test and POST the following JSON: 
(I know it is not and actual base64 encoding).

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
  //  Testing JSON
        {"base64Encoding":"asdasdasdasd"}
  //

   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
using RewoServiceLayer.RequestDTOs;
using System.Data.Entity;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.ServiceModel;
using ServiceStack.Configuration;
using ServiceStack.Common;
using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth;
using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace Blah.Services
{

    public class ImageResponse
    {
        public images image { get; set; }
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; } //Where Exceptions get auto-serialized 
    }

    public class ImageRequest
    {
        public String base64Encoding;
    }

    public class ImageService : Service
    {
        //Give me something that looks like this: 
        //"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABG4...YII=";
        public ImageResponse Post(ImageRequest request)
        {
            String base64EncodingImg = request.base64Encoding;
            using (var db = new BlahDB())
            {
                //save to db
                images imgToSave = new images();
                //get base64
                string base64 = base64EncodingImg.Substring(base64EncodingImg.IndexOf(',') + 1);
                base64 = base64.Trim('\0');
                byte[] imgBinData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
                //get the 
                imgToSave.image_type = base64EncodingImg.Substring(0,base64EncodingImg.IndexOf(','));
                db.images.Add(imgToSave);
                db.SaveChanges();
                //then save string contents to disk using ID
                imgToSave.image_disk_loc = getPathFromImage(imgToSave);
                writeByteArrToDisk(imgBinData, imgToSave.image_disk_loc);
                db.SaveChanges();

                ImageResponse imgResponse = new ImageResponse();
                imgResponse.image = imgToSave;
                return imgResponse;
            }
        }
        private Boolean writeByteArrToDisk(byte[] toWrite, String path)
        {
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(path, toWrite);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return false;
            }
        }

        private String getAbsolutePathToImagesFolder()
        {
            return HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/UploadedImages");
        }

        private String getPathFromImage(images imgModel)
        {
            if (imgModel.image_disk_loc.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                return getAbsolutePathToImagesFolder() + imgModel.image_id;
            }
            else
            {
                return imgModel.image_disk_loc;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

I am getting the following error and it does not hit the Post Method when I debug:

```
{
    "responseStatus": {
        "errorCode": "NullReferenceException",
        "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
        "stackTrace": "   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Utils.FilterAttributeCache.GetRequestFilterAttributes(Type requestDtoType)\r\n   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.EndpointHost.ApplyRequestFilters(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object requestDto)\r\n   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see your `images` class but I think you need to change

```
ROUTES.Add<images>("/Images");
```

To

```
ROUTES.Add<ImageRequest>("/Images")
```

since the Post on your ImageService is looking for a request of type ImageRequest.

Comment: You are correct, I must of missed this when I was refactoring thank you so much!!